# query to remove first value from " For XML PATH "

Tags: sql-server

i have a query like this :

```
 Select ','''+ aa.KodeVerifikasi +''''    
 From TVerifikasiPOFakturHeader as aa (NOLOCK)        
 inner join TVerifikasiPOFakturDetail as bb (NOLOCK) on  aa.KodeVerifikasi=bb.KodeVerifikasi        
 Where aa.KodePO='TS/01/15/00183' 
 group by aa.KodeVerifikasi       
 order by aa.KodeVerifikasi        
 For XML PATH ('')
```

and i get the return like this :

```
,'val6','val4','val5','val9'
```

but i want to remove first character "," and i want to get return like this :

```
'val6','val4','val5','val9'
```

when i using substring : SUBSTRING(','''+ aa.KodeVerifikasi +'''', 2, 8000) 
i get return like this : 'val6''val4''val5''val9'

please help me,,, and thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `LEFT` function. Append the , at the end and remove it using `LEFT` function.

```
SELECT LEFT(result, Len(result) - 1)
FROM   (SELECT '''' + aa.KodeVerifikasi + ''','
        FROM   TVerifikasiPOFakturHeader AS aa (NOLOCK)
               INNER JOIN TVerifikasiPOFakturDetail AS bb (NOLOCK)
                       ON aa.KodeVerifikasi = bb.KodeVerifikasi
        WHERE  aa.KodePO = 'TS/01/15/00183'
        GROUP  BY aa.KodeVerifikasi
        ORDER  BY aa.KodeVerifikasi
        FOR XML PATH ('')) a (result)
```

Or you can wrap your current query in `STUFF` function and trim the first character

Comment: @JaydipJ - Big Nooo

Comment: Ha ha ha just notice you appended comma `+ ''','` :)

Answer (score 2):

USE STUFF

```
SELECT STUFF((
               your query here
             ),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select STUFF( (Select ','''+ aa.KodeVerifikasi +''''    
 From TVerifikasiPOFakturHeader as aa (NOLOCK)        
 inner join TVerifikasiPOFakturDetail as bb (NOLOCK) 
 on aa.KodeVerifikasi=bb.KodeVerifikasi        
 Where aa.KodePO='TS/01/15/00183' 
 group by aa.KodeVerifikasi       
 order by aa.KodeVerifikasi        
 For XML PATH ('') ),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

One more simple way is as below

```
 DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)

 SELECT @str = ISNULL(@str+',','') + QUOTENAME(aa.KodeVerifikasi,'''') 

 From TVerifikasiPOFakturHeader as aa (NOLOCK)        

 INNER JOIN TVerifikasiPOFakturDetail as bb (NOLOCK) on
                                aa.KodeVerifikasi=bb.KodeVerifikasi        

 WHERE aa.KodePO='TS/01/15/00183' 

 GROUP BY aa.KodeVerifikasi       

 ORDER BY aa.KodeVerifikasi        

 SELECT @str
```